# How should I return JWT token to user after login?

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt

What is preferred, most canonical way to return newly generated token to user after succeful login?

I could:

- return it straight in the body of respose
- return is as json: `{token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"}`
- maybe return empty body and return is as `Authorization` token?

For know I use 1st option, but I wonder if there is any best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return in response body as a json property is the most common and convinient way of doing this. In response body setting something like below:

```
resp: { token:" " }
```

Generally we donot change the headers in the API responses.